# How to do some cod while a Virtual Button in pressed down in unity

Tags: c#, button, unity-game-engine, while-loop

I have a code for firing and want repeat the code while a virtual button is pressed in unity what I have to do?
Is there any solution to do this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please provide more detail, and be more specific about what you want to do? What code are you trying to run when a button is pressed? Can you show us what you've already accomplished so far? Are you trying to use a UI button element, or something custom-made? Can you show a screenshot of your scene, and the object you want to trigger the firing on click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to design an automatic firearm in your game?

If so, then:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Autof : MonoBehaviour {
    float fireDelay = 0f; // the delay between shots

    // Assume that the function below is your code to fire your weapon:
    void FireWeapon()
    {
        Debug.Log("Fire!!!");
    }

    // The function below activates the FireWeapon function
    void AutoFire(float fireRate)
    {
        if (fireDelay < fireRate)
        {
            fireDelay += Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (fireDelay >= fireRate)
        {
            FireWeapon();
            fireDelay = 0f;
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        AutoFire(0.2f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `OnPointerDown` and   `OnPointerUp` functions. Set a variable to `true` or `false` when appropriate function is called then check if that variable is `true` in the `Update` function. Attach the code below to the `Image` you want to detect the press down on.

```
public class Pressed : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler,IPointerUpHandler
{
    bool pressed = false;

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        pressed = true;
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        pressed = false;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (pressed)
        {
            Debug.Log("Pressed Down!");
            //Put Code to repeat here
        }
    }
}
```

Note that if that `Image` is not an Image component and just a `SpriteRenderer`, you must attach `Collider 2D` to that `SpriteRenderer` then attach [`Physics 2D Raycaster`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Physics2DRaycaster.html) to the Camera.